# TimeZoneInfo object

Tags: c#, timezone

I want to use TimeZoneInfo, as I understood the TimeZoneInfo object take its information from the registry - but I dont understand why this object doesnot expose an enum or something else that contains all the TimeZone IDs - is it because the IDs are diffrent between duffrent windows? and if so the single way that I can get something time zone - first I should get all TimeZone's IDs by invoke GetSystemTimeZones() and then find the time zone that I want?

Thanks,

Comment: It might be just me in the morning, but I think if you rephrase your question by breaking it into smaller sentences, and then clearly indicate **what exactly your question is**, it'll be easier for the community to help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Timezones change](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/world/americas/7134927.stm) - as indeed do the *rules* for each (DST etc).

Enums do not.

For the same reason, culture-info has a string identifier, not an enum. This also allows you to define your own cultures at runtime, and pick up changes as the OS gets updates from external sources. I actually hope you can do the same with timezones (define your own).